# Updating EF String connection C#

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, entity-framework-6

I have a vs installer which updates the connection string of Entity Framework in the app config. Using XmlDocument.

This is the code:

```
 attribute.Value = "metadata=res://*/Veterinaria.csdl|res://*/Veterinaria.ssdl|res://*/Veterinaria.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=" + Context.Parameters["InstanciaSQL"] + ";initial catalog=Sistema_Veterinaria;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;";
```

The problem is that in the xml instead of writing "string="data source=", it writes "string=&quot;data source"

It seems an encoding problem. Already tryed &&,&amp,\", with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
attribute.Value = "metadata=res://*/Veterinaria.csdl|res://*/Veterinaria.ssdl|res://*/Veterinaria.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=" + "\"" + ";data source=" + Context.Parameters["InstanciaSQL"] + ";initial catalog=Sistema_Veterinaria;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"";
```

Use + for concatenation in your code and try that way.

Comment: Please don't post comments (which this is) in the answers section. Wait until you can post comments appropriately.